# Timer interrupts in ARM processor QEMU not occurring

Tags: c, assembly, timer, arm, qemu

I am trying to get interrupts to work on an ARM processor using QEMU. I have tried Google and various attempts to solve it, but I cannot get my IRQ handler to be called.

I also tried keyboard interrupts, which did not work either. I think the book I have may have a few mistakes, as the UART driver ended up being slightly different than described.

My assembly code:

```
.code 32

    .global start, vectors_start, vectors_end, lock, unlock
start:
    LDR sp, =stack_top
    BL copy_vector
    MSR cpsr, #0x92
    LDR sp, =irq_stack_top
    MSR cpsr, #0x13
    bl unlock


    BL main
    B .
irq_handler:
    sub lr, lr, #4
    stmfd sp!, {r0-r12, lr}
    bl IRQ_handler
    ldmfd sp!, {r0-r12, pc}^

vectors_start:
    LDR PC, reset_handler_addr
    LDR PC, undef_handler_addr
    LDR PC, swi_handler_addr
    LDR PC, prefetch_abort_handler_addr
    LDR PC, data_abort_handler_addr
    B .
    LDR PC, irq_handler_addr
    LDR PC, fiq_handler_addr
    reset_handler_addr: .word start
    undef_handler_addr: .word undef_handler
    swi_handler_addr:  .word swi_handler
    prefetch_abort_handler_addr: .word prefetch_abort_handler
    data_abort_handler_addr: .word data_abort_handler
    irq_handler_addr: .word irq_handler
    fiq_handler_addr: .word fiq_handler
vectors_end:

lock:
    MRS r0, CPSR
    ORR r0,r0,#0x80
    MSR CPSR, r0
    mov PC, lr
unlock:
    MRS r0,CPSR
    BIC r0,r0,#0x80
    MSR CPSR, r0
    mov PC, lr
```

Relevant C functions:

```c
void copy_vector(void){
    extern u32 vectors_start, vectors_end;
    u32 *vectors_src = &vectors_start;
    u32 *vectors_dst = (u32 *) 0;
    while (vectors_src<&vectors_end){
        *vectors_dst++ = *vectors_src++;
    }
}

// this function has been modified somewhat because the book was incomplete
// the print statement never prints 

void IRQ_handler(void){
    int vicstatus = 0;
    uprints(uarts,"in interupt");
   // int vicstatus = 0;

    if(1){
        if(*(tp[0]->base+TVALUE)==0){
            timer_handler(0);
        }
        if(*(tp[1]->base+TVALUE)==0){
            timer_handler(1);
        }

    }

    if( 1){
        if(*(tp[2]->base+TVALUE)==0){
            timer_handler(2);
        }
        if(*(tp[3]->base+TVALUE)==0){
            timer_handler(3);
        }

    }

}

void timer_init()
{
  //  timers[0].base = (u32*) 0x101E2000;
  //  timers[1].base = (u32*) 0x101E2020;
   // timers[2].base = (u32*) 0x101E3000;
   // timers[3].base = (u32*) 0x101E3020;
    int i; TIMER * tp;
    for (i = 0; i<4; ++i){
        tp = &timers[i];
        if(i==0) tp->base = (u32*) 0x101E2000;
        if(i==1) tp->base = (u32*) 0x101E2020;
        if (i == 2) tp->base = (u32*) 0x101E3000;
        if (i == 3) tp->base = (u32*) 0x101E3020;



        *(tp->base+TLOAD) = 0x0;
        *(tp->base+TVALUE) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        *(tp->base+TRIS) = 0x0;
        *(tp->base+TMIS) = 0x0;
        *(tp->base+TLOAD) = 0x100;
        *(tp->base+TCNTL) = 0x66;
        *(tp->base+TBGLOAD) = 0x1C00;
         *(tp->base ) |= (unsigned int)(1<<6);
        tp->tick = 0;
        ///uprints(uarts,"timer init");
    }
}
```

When I reset the machine in QEMU I get the message Timer with delta zero disabling.

I can get the message to disappear by changing: `*(tp->base+TLOAD) = 0x0;`
to `*(tp->base+TLOAD) = 0x1;` but the timer still doesn't work.

Lastly, my build script is:

```
arm-none-eabi-as -o start3.o start3.s
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c main3.c
arm-none-eabi-ld -T t.ld -o start3.elf start3.o main3.o
arm-none-eabi-nm start3.elf
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary start3.elf start3.bin

qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel start3.bin
```

edit: in addition here is the disassembled code from my main.c file (which includes a few other c files for the drivers)

the board is the versatilepb which according to the docs emulates the following:
ARM926E, ARM1136 or Cortex-A8 CPU

```
00000000 <uart_init>:
   0:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
   8:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
   c:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
  10:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
  14:   ea000011    b   60 <uart_init+0x60>
  18:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
  1c:   e1a03183    lsl r3, r3, #3
  20:   e59f2064    ldr r2, [pc, #100]  ; 8c <uart_init+0x8c>
  24:   e0833002    add r3, r3, r2
  28:   e50b300c    str r3, [fp, #-12]
  2c:   e51b2008    ldr r2, [fp, #-8]
  30:   e59f3058    ldr r3, [pc, #88]   ; 90 <uart_init+0x90>
  34:   e0823003    add r3, r2, r3
  38:   e1a03603    lsl r3, r3, #12
  3c:   e1a02003    mov r2, r3
  40:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
  44:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
  48:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
  4c:   e51b2008    ldr r2, [fp, #-8]
  50:   e5832004    str r2, [r3, #4]
  54:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
  58:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
  5c:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
  60:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
  64:   e3530003    cmp r3, #3
  68:   daffffea    ble 18 <uart_init+0x18>
  6c:   e59f3018    ldr r3, [pc, #24]   ; 8c <uart_init+0x8c>
  70:   e59f201c    ldr r2, [pc, #28]   ; 94 <uart_init+0x94>
  74:   e5832018    str r2, [r3, #24]
  78:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  7c:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  80:   e28bd000    add sp, fp, #0
  84:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
  88:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  8c:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
  90:   000101f1    .word   0x000101f1
  94:   10009000    .word   0x10009000

00000098 <ugetc>:
  98:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
  9c:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
  a0:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
  a4:   e50b0008    str r0, [fp, #-8]
  a8:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  ac:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
  b0:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
  b4:   e2833018    add r3, r3, #24
  b8:   e5d33000    ldrb    r3, [r3]
  bc:   e2033010    and r3, r3, #16
  c0:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
  c4:   1afffff8    bne ac <ugetc+0x14>
  c8:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
  cc:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
  d0:   e5d33000    ldrb    r3, [r3]
  d4:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  d8:   e28bd000    add sp, fp, #0
  dc:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
  e0:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

000000e4 <uputc>:
  e4:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
  e8:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
  ec:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
  f0:   e50b0008    str r0, [fp, #-8]
  f4:   e1a03001    mov r3, r1
  f8:   e54b3009    strb    r3, [fp, #-9]
  fc:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 100:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 104:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 108:   e2833018    add r3, r3, #24
 10c:   e5d33000    ldrb    r3, [r3]
 110:   e2033020    and r3, r3, #32
 114:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
 118:   1afffff8    bne 100 <uputc+0x1c>
 11c:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 120:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 124:   e55b2009    ldrb    r2, [fp, #-9]
 128:   e5c32000    strb    r2, [r3]
 12c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 130:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
 134:   e28bd000    add sp, fp, #0
 138:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
 13c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000140 <ugets>:
 140:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
 144:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
 148:   e24dd008    sub sp, sp, #8
 14c:   e50b0008    str r0, [fp, #-8]
 150:   e50b100c    str r1, [fp, #-12]
 154:   ea000007    b   178 <ugets+0x38>
 158:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 15c:   e5d33000    ldrb    r3, [r3]
 160:   e1a01003    mov r1, r3
 164:   e51b0008    ldr r0, [fp, #-8]
 168:   ebfffffe    bl  e4 <uputc>
 16c:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 170:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
 174:   e50b300c    str r3, [fp, #-12]
 178:   e51b0008    ldr r0, [fp, #-8]
 17c:   ebfffffe    bl  98 <ugetc>
 180:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
 184:   e20320ff    and r2, r3, #255    ; 0xff
 188:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 18c:   e5c32000    strb    r2, [r3]
 190:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 194:   e5d33000    ldrb    r3, [r3]
 198:   e353000d    cmp r3, #13
 19c:   1affffed    bne 158 <ugets+0x18>
 1a0:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 1a4:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0
 1a8:   e5c32000    strb    r2, [r3]
 1ac:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 1b0:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
 1b4:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
 1b8:   e8bd4800    pop {fp, lr}
 1bc:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

000001c0 <uprints>:
 1c0:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
 1c4:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
 1c8:   e24dd008    sub sp, sp, #8
 1cc:   e50b0008    str r0, [fp, #-8]
 1d0:   e50b100c    str r1, [fp, #-12]
 1d4:   ea000006    b   1f4 <uprints+0x34>
 1d8:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 1dc:   e2832001    add r2, r3, #1
 1e0:   e50b200c    str r2, [fp, #-12]
 1e4:   e5d33000    ldrb    r3, [r3]
 1e8:   e1a01003    mov r1, r3
 1ec:   e51b0008    ldr r0, [fp, #-8]
 1f0:   ebfffffe    bl  e4 <uputc>
 1f4:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 1f8:   e5d33000    ldrb    r3, [r3]
 1fc:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
 200:   1afffff4    bne 1d8 <uprints+0x18>
 204:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 208:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
 20c:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
 210:   e8bd4800    pop {fp, lr}
 214:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000218 <fbuf_init>:
 218:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
 21c:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
 220:   e59f3060    ldr r3, [pc, #96]   ; 288 <fbuf_init+0x70>
 224:   e3a02602    mov r2, #2097152    ; 0x200000
 228:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 22c:   e59f3058    ldr r3, [pc, #88]   ; 28c <fbuf_init+0x74>
 230:   e59f2058    ldr r2, [pc, #88]   ; 290 <fbuf_init+0x78>
 234:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 238:   e59f3054    ldr r3, [pc, #84]   ; 294 <fbuf_init+0x7c>
 23c:   e59f2054    ldr r2, [pc, #84]   ; 298 <fbuf_init+0x80>
 240:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 244:   e59f3050    ldr r3, [pc, #80]   ; 29c <fbuf_init+0x84>
 248:   e59f2050    ldr r2, [pc, #80]   ; 2a0 <fbuf_init+0x88>
 24c:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 250:   e59f304c    ldr r3, [pc, #76]   ; 2a4 <fbuf_init+0x8c>
 254:   e59f204c    ldr r2, [pc, #76]   ; 2a8 <fbuf_init+0x90>
 258:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 25c:   e59f3048    ldr r3, [pc, #72]   ; 2ac <fbuf_init+0x94>
 260:   e3a02602    mov r2, #2097152    ; 0x200000
 264:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 268:   e59f3040    ldr r3, [pc, #64]   ; 2b0 <fbuf_init+0x98>
 26c:   e59f2040    ldr r2, [pc, #64]   ; 2b4 <fbuf_init+0x9c>
 270:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 274:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 278:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
 27c:   e28bd000    add sp, fp, #0
 280:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
 284:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
 288:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
 28c:   1000001c    .word   0x1000001c
 290:   00002c77    .word   0x00002c77
 294:   10120000    .word   0x10120000
 298:   3f1f3f9c    .word   0x3f1f3f9c
 29c:   10120004    .word   0x10120004
 2a0:   090b61df    .word   0x090b61df
 2a4:   10120008    .word   0x10120008
 2a8:   071f1800    .word   0x071f1800
 2ac:   10120010    .word   0x10120010
 2b0:   10120018    .word   0x10120018
 2b4:   0000082b    .word   0x0000082b

000002b8 <draw_box>:
 2b8:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
 2bc:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
 2c0:   e24dd01c    sub sp, sp, #28
 2c4:   e50b0010    str r0, [fp, #-16]
 2c8:   e50b1014    str r1, [fp, #-20]  ; 0xffffffec
 2cc:   e50b2018    str r2, [fp, #-24]  ; 0xffffffe8
 2d0:   e50b301c    str r3, [fp, #-28]  ; 0xffffffe4
 2d4:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
 2d8:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 2dc:   ea00001c    b   354 <draw_box+0x9c>
 2e0:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
 2e4:   e50b300c    str r3, [fp, #-12]
 2e8:   ea000012    b   338 <draw_box+0x80>
 2ec:   e59f3084    ldr r3, [pc, #132]  ; 378 <draw_box+0xc0>
 2f0:   e5932000    ldr r2, [r3]
 2f4:   e51b100c    ldr r1, [fp, #-12]
 2f8:   e51b3014    ldr r3, [fp, #-20]  ; 0xffffffec
 2fc:   e0813003    add r3, r1, r3
 300:   e59f1074    ldr r1, [pc, #116]  ; 37c <draw_box+0xc4>
 304:   e5911000    ldr r1, [r1]
 308:   e0010193    mul r1, r3, r1
 30c:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 310:   e0811003    add r1, r1, r3
 314:   e51b3010    ldr r3, [fp, #-16]
 318:   e0813003    add r3, r1, r3
 31c:   e1a03103    lsl r3, r3, #2
 320:   e0823003    add r3, r2, r3
 324:   e51b201c    ldr r2, [fp, #-28]  ; 0xffffffe4
 328:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 32c:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 330:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
 334:   e50b300c    str r3, [fp, #-12]
 338:   e51b200c    ldr r2, [fp, #-12]
 33c:   e51b3018    ldr r3, [fp, #-24]  ; 0xffffffe8
 340:   e1520003    cmp r2, r3
 344:   baffffe8    blt 2ec <draw_box+0x34>
 348:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 34c:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
 350:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 354:   e51b2008    ldr r2, [fp, #-8]
 358:   e51b3018    ldr r3, [fp, #-24]  ; 0xffffffe8
 35c:   e1520003    cmp r2, r3
 360:   baffffde    blt 2e0 <draw_box+0x28>
 364:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 368:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 36c:   e28bd000    add sp, fp, #0
 370:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
 374:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    ...

00000380 <timer_init>:
 380:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
 384:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
 388:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
 38c:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
 390:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 394:   ea000048    b   4bc <timer_init+0x13c>
 398:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 39c:   e1a03183    lsl r3, r3, #3
 3a0:   e59f2134    ldr r2, [pc, #308]  ; 4dc <timer_init+0x15c>
 3a4:   e0833002    add r3, r3, r2
 3a8:   e50b300c    str r3, [fp, #-12]
 3ac:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 3b0:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
 3b4:   1a000002    bne 3c4 <timer_init+0x44>
 3b8:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 3bc:   e59f211c    ldr r2, [pc, #284]  ; 4e0 <timer_init+0x160>
 3c0:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 3c4:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 3c8:   e3530001    cmp r3, #1
 3cc:   1a000002    bne 3dc <timer_init+0x5c>
 3d0:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 3d4:   e59f2108    ldr r2, [pc, #264]  ; 4e4 <timer_init+0x164>
 3d8:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 3dc:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 3e0:   e3530002    cmp r3, #2
 3e4:   1a000002    bne 3f4 <timer_init+0x74>
 3e8:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 3ec:   e59f20f4    ldr r2, [pc, #244]  ; 4e8 <timer_init+0x168>
 3f0:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 3f4:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 3f8:   e3530003    cmp r3, #3
 3fc:   1a000002    bne 40c <timer_init+0x8c>
 400:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 404:   e59f20e0    ldr r2, [pc, #224]  ; 4ec <timer_init+0x16c>
 408:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 40c:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 410:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 414:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0
 418:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 41c:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 420:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 424:   e2833004    add r3, r3, #4
 428:   e3e02000    mvn r2, #0
 42c:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 430:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 434:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 438:   e2833010    add r3, r3, #16
 43c:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0
 440:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 444:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 448:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 44c:   e2833014    add r3, r3, #20
 450:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0
 454:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 458:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 45c:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 460:   e3a02c01    mov r2, #256    ; 0x100
 464:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 468:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 46c:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 470:   e2833008    add r3, r3, #8
 474:   e3a02066    mov r2, #102    ; 0x66
 478:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 47c:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 480:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 484:   e2833018    add r3, r3, #24
 488:   e3a02b07    mov r2, #7168   ; 0x1c00
 48c:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 490:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 494:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 498:   e5932000    ldr r2, [r3]
 49c:   e3822040    orr r2, r2, #64 ; 0x40
 4a0:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 4a4:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 4a8:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0
 4ac:   e5832004    str r2, [r3, #4]
 4b0:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 4b4:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
 4b8:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 4bc:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 4c0:   e3530003    cmp r3, #3
 4c4:   daffffb3    ble 398 <timer_init+0x18>
 4c8:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 4cc:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 4d0:   e28bd000    add sp, fp, #0
 4d4:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
 4d8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
 4dc:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
 4e0:   101e2000    .word   0x101e2000
 4e4:   101e2020    .word   0x101e2020
 4e8:   101e3000    .word   0x101e3000
 4ec:   101e3020    .word   0x101e3020

000004f0 <timer_clearInterupt>:
 4f0:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
 4f4:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
 4f8:   e24dd014    sub sp, sp, #20
 4fc:   e50b0010    str r0, [fp, #-16]
 500:   e51b3010    ldr r3, [fp, #-16]
 504:   e1a03183    lsl r3, r3, #3
 508:   e59f2028    ldr r2, [pc, #40]   ; 538 <timer_clearInterupt+0x48>
 50c:   e0833002    add r3, r3, r2
 510:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 514:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 518:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 51c:   e283300c    add r3, r3, #12
 520:   e3e02000    mvn r2, #0
 524:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 528:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 52c:   e28bd000    add sp, fp, #0
 530:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
 534:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
 538:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

0000053c <timer_handler>:
 53c:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
 540:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
 544:   e24dd010    sub sp, sp, #16
 548:   e50b0010    str r0, [fp, #-16]
 54c:   e51b3010    ldr r3, [fp, #-16]
 550:   e1a03183    lsl r3, r3, #3
 554:   e59f203c    ldr r2, [pc, #60]   ; 598 <timer_handler+0x5c>
 558:   e0833002    add r3, r3, r2
 55c:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 560:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 564:   e5933004    ldr r3, [r3, #4]
 568:   e2832001    add r2, r3, #1
 56c:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 570:   e5832004    str r2, [r3, #4]
 574:   e51b0010    ldr r0, [fp, #-16]
 578:   ebfffffe    bl  4f0 <timer_clearInterupt>
 57c:   e59f1018    ldr r1, [pc, #24]   ; 59c <timer_handler+0x60>
 580:   e59f0018    ldr r0, [pc, #24]   ; 5a0 <timer_handler+0x64>
 584:   ebfffffe    bl  1c0 <uprints>
 588:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 58c:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
 590:   e8bd4800    pop {fp, lr}
 594:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    ...

000005a4 <timer_start>:
 5a4:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
 5a8:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
 5ac:   e24dd010    sub sp, sp, #16
 5b0:   e50b0010    str r0, [fp, #-16]
 5b4:   e59f1044    ldr r1, [pc, #68]   ; 600 <timer_start+0x5c>
 5b8:   e59f0044    ldr r0, [pc, #68]   ; 604 <timer_start+0x60>
 5bc:   ebfffffe    bl  1c0 <uprints>
 5c0:   e51b3010    ldr r3, [fp, #-16]
 5c4:   e1a03183    lsl r3, r3, #3
 5c8:   e59f2038    ldr r2, [pc, #56]   ; 608 <timer_start+0x64>
 5cc:   e0833002    add r3, r3, r2
 5d0:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 5d4:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 5d8:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 5dc:   e2832008    add r2, r3, #8
 5e0:   e5922000    ldr r2, [r2]
 5e4:   e2833008    add r3, r3, #8
 5e8:   e3822080    orr r2, r2, #128    ; 0x80
 5ec:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 5f0:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 5f4:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
 5f8:   e8bd4800    pop {fp, lr}
 5fc:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
 600:   00000010    .word   0x00000010
    ...

0000060c <timer_stop>:
 60c:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
 610:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
 614:   e24dd014    sub sp, sp, #20
 618:   e50b0010    str r0, [fp, #-16]
 61c:   e51b3010    ldr r3, [fp, #-16]
 620:   e1a03183    lsl r3, r3, #3
 624:   e59f2028    ldr r2, [pc, #40]   ; 654 <timer_stop+0x48>
 628:   e0833002    add r3, r3, r2
 62c:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 630:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 634:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 638:   e2833008    add r3, r3, #8
 63c:   e3a0207f    mov r2, #127    ; 0x7f
 640:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 644:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 648:   e28bd000    add sp, fp, #0
 64c:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
 650:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
 654:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

00000658 <undef_handler>:
 658:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
 65c:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
 660:   e59f1014    ldr r1, [pc, #20]   ; 67c <undef_handler+0x24>
 664:   e59f0014    ldr r0, [pc, #20]   ; 680 <undef_handler+0x28>
 668:   ebfffffe    bl  1c0 <uprints>
 66c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 670:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
 674:   e8bd4800    pop {fp, lr}
 678:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
 67c:   00000020    .word   0x00000020
 680:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

00000684 <swi_handler>:
 684:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
 688:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
 68c:   e59f1014    ldr r1, [pc, #20]   ; 6a8 <swi_handler+0x24>
 690:   e59f0014    ldr r0, [pc, #20]   ; 6ac <swi_handler+0x28>
 694:   ebfffffe    bl  1c0 <uprints>
 698:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 69c:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
 6a0:   e8bd4800    pop {fp, lr}
 6a4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
 6a8:   00000020    .word   0x00000020
 6ac:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

000006b0 <prefetch_abort_handler>:
 6b0:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
 6b4:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
 6b8:   e59f1014    ldr r1, [pc, #20]   ; 6d4 <prefetch_abort_handler+0x24>
 6bc:   e59f0014    ldr r0, [pc, #20]   ; 6d8 <prefetch_abort_handler+0x28>
 6c0:   ebfffffe    bl  1c0 <uprints>
 6c4:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 6c8:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
 6cc:   e8bd4800    pop {fp, lr}
 6d0:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
 6d4:   00000020    .word   0x00000020
 6d8:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

000006dc <data_abort_handler>:
 6dc:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
 6e0:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
 6e4:   e59f1014    ldr r1, [pc, #20]   ; 700 <data_abort_handler+0x24>
 6e8:   e59f0014    ldr r0, [pc, #20]   ; 704 <data_abort_handler+0x28>
 6ec:   ebfffffe    bl  1c0 <uprints>
 6f0:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 6f4:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
 6f8:   e8bd4800    pop {fp, lr}
 6fc:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
 700:   00000020    .word   0x00000020
 704:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

00000708 <fiq_handler>:
 708:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
 70c:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
 710:   e59f1014    ldr r1, [pc, #20]   ; 72c <fiq_handler+0x24>
 714:   e59f0014    ldr r0, [pc, #20]   ; 730 <fiq_handler+0x28>
 718:   ebfffffe    bl  1c0 <uprints>
 71c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 720:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
 724:   e8bd4800    pop {fp, lr}
 728:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
 72c:   00000020    .word   0x00000020
 730:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

00000734 <copy_vector>:
 734:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
 738:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
 73c:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
 740:   e59f3050    ldr r3, [pc, #80]   ; 798 <copy_vector+0x64>
 744:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 748:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
 74c:   e50b300c    str r3, [fp, #-12]
 750:   ea000007    b   774 <copy_vector+0x40>
 754:   e51b2008    ldr r2, [fp, #-8]
 758:   e2823004    add r3, r2, #4
 75c:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 760:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
 764:   e2831004    add r1, r3, #4
 768:   e50b100c    str r1, [fp, #-12]
 76c:   e5922000    ldr r2, [r2]
 770:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 774:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 778:   e59f201c    ldr r2, [pc, #28]   ; 79c <copy_vector+0x68>
 77c:   e1530002    cmp r3, r2
 780:   3afffff3    bcc 754 <copy_vector+0x20>
 784:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 788:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 78c:   e28bd000    add sp, fp, #0
 790:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
 794:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    ...

000007a0 <kbd_init>:
 7a0:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
 7a4:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
 7a8:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
 7ac:   e59f302c    ldr r3, [pc, #44]   ; 7e0 <kbd_init+0x40>
 7b0:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 7b4:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 7b8:   e3a02014    mov r2, #20
 7bc:   e5c32000    strb    r2, [r3]
 7c0:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 7c4:   e283300c    add r3, r3, #12
 7c8:   e3a02008    mov r2, #8
 7cc:   e5c32000    strb    r2, [r3]
 7d0:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 7d4:   e28bd000    add sp, fp, #0
 7d8:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
 7dc:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
 7e0:   10006000    .word   0x10006000

000007e4 <IRQ_handler>:
 7e4:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
 7e8:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
 7ec:   e24dd008    sub sp, sp, #8
 7f0:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
 7f4:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 7f8:   e59f10a4    ldr r1, [pc, #164]  ; 8a4 <IRQ_handler+0xc0>
 7fc:   e59f00a4    ldr r0, [pc, #164]  ; 8a8 <IRQ_handler+0xc4>
 800:   ebfffffe    bl  1c0 <uprints>
 804:   e59f30a0    ldr r3, [pc, #160]  ; 8ac <IRQ_handler+0xc8>
 808:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 80c:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 810:   e2833004    add r3, r3, #4
 814:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 818:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
 81c:   1a000001    bne 828 <IRQ_handler+0x44>
 820:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
 824:   ebfffffe    bl  53c <timer_handler>
 828:   e59f307c    ldr r3, [pc, #124]  ; 8ac <IRQ_handler+0xc8>
 82c:   e5933004    ldr r3, [r3, #4]
 830:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 834:   e2833004    add r3, r3, #4
 838:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 83c:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
 840:   1a000001    bne 84c <IRQ_handler+0x68>
 844:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
 848:   ebfffffe    bl  53c <timer_handler>
 84c:   e59f3058    ldr r3, [pc, #88]   ; 8ac <IRQ_handler+0xc8>
 850:   e5933008    ldr r3, [r3, #8]
 854:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 858:   e2833004    add r3, r3, #4
 85c:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 860:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
 864:   1a000001    bne 870 <IRQ_handler+0x8c>
 868:   e3a00002    mov r0, #2
 86c:   ebfffffe    bl  53c <timer_handler>
 870:   e59f3034    ldr r3, [pc, #52]   ; 8ac <IRQ_handler+0xc8>
 874:   e593300c    ldr r3, [r3, #12]
 878:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 87c:   e2833004    add r3, r3, #4
 880:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
 884:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
 888:   1a000001    bne 894 <IRQ_handler+0xb0>
 88c:   e3a00003    mov r0, #3
 890:   ebfffffe    bl  53c <timer_handler>
 894:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 898:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
 89c:   e8bd4800    pop {fp, lr}
 8a0:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
 8a4:   00000030    .word   0x00000030
    ...

000008b0 <main>:
 8b0:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
 8b4:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
 8b8:   e24dd010    sub sp, sp, #16
 8bc:   ebfffffe    bl  218 <fbuf_init>
 8c0:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <uart_init>
 8c4:   ebfffffe    bl  380 <timer_init>
 8c8:   ebfffffe    bl  7a0 <kbd_init>
 8cc:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
 8d0:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 8d4:   ea00000b    b   908 <main+0x58>
 8d8:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 8dc:   e1a03183    lsl r3, r3, #3
 8e0:   e59f20dc    ldr r2, [pc, #220]  ; 9c4 <main+0x114>
 8e4:   e0832002    add r2, r3, r2
 8e8:   e59f10d8    ldr r1, [pc, #216]  ; 9c8 <main+0x118>
 8ec:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 8f0:   e7812103    str r2, [r1, r3, lsl #2]
 8f4:   e51b0008    ldr r0, [fp, #-8]
 8f8:   ebfffffe    bl  5a4 <timer_start>
 8fc:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 900:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
 904:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
 908:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
 90c:   e3530003    cmp r3, #3
 910:   dafffff0    ble 8d8 <main+0x28>
 914:   e59f10b0    ldr r1, [pc, #176]  ; 9cc <main+0x11c>
 918:   e59f00b0    ldr r0, [pc, #176]  ; 9d0 <main+0x120>
 91c:   ebfffffe    bl  1c0 <uprints>
 920:   e59f309c    ldr r3, [pc, #156]  ; 9c4 <main+0x114>
 924:   e5931004    ldr r1, [r3, #4]
 928:   e59f30a4    ldr r3, [pc, #164]  ; 9d4 <main+0x124>
 92c:   e0c32391    smull   r2, r3, r1, r3
 930:   e1a021c3    asr r2, r3, #3
 934:   e1a03fc1    asr r3, r1, #31
 938:   e0422003    sub r2, r2, r3
 93c:   e1a03002    mov r3, r2
 940:   e1a03183    lsl r3, r3, #3
 944:   e0433002    sub r3, r3, r2
 948:   e1a03183    lsl r3, r3, #3
 94c:   e0433002    sub r3, r3, r2
 950:   e1a03103    lsl r3, r3, #2
 954:   e0412003    sub r2, r1, r3
 958:   e1a03002    mov r3, r2
 95c:   e54b3009    strb    r3, [fp, #-9]
 960:   e55b3009    ldrb    r3, [fp, #-9]
 964:   e2833037    add r3, r3, #55 ; 0x37
 968:   e20330ff    and r3, r3, #255    ; 0xff
 96c:   e1a01003    mov r1, r3
 970:   e59f0058    ldr r0, [pc, #88]   ; 9d0 <main+0x120>
 974:   ebfffffe    bl  e4 <uputc>
 978:   e55b3009    ldrb    r3, [fp, #-9]
 97c:   e383386e    orr r3, r3, #7208960    ; 0x6e0000
 980:   e3833001    orr r3, r3, #1
 984:   e50b3010    str r3, [fp, #-16]
 988:   e51b3010    ldr r3, [fp, #-16]
 98c:   e3a02064    mov r2, #100    ; 0x64
 990:   e3a0100a    mov r1, #10
 994:   e3a0000a    mov r0, #10
 998:   ebfffffe    bl  2b8 <draw_box>
 99c:   e59f3020    ldr r3, [pc, #32]   ; 9c4 <main+0x114>
 9a0:   e5933004    ldr r3, [r3, #4]
 9a4:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
 9a8:   0affffdc    beq 920 <main+0x70>
 9ac:   e3a03b32    mov r3, #51200  ; 0xc800
 9b0:   e3a02032    mov r2, #50 ; 0x32
 9b4:   e3a010fa    mov r1, #250    ; 0xfa
 9b8:   e3a000c8    mov r0, #200    ; 0xc8
 9bc:   ebfffffe    bl  2b8 <draw_box>
 9c0:   eaffffd6    b   920 <main+0x70>
    ...
 9cc:   0000003c    .word   0x0000003c
 9d0:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
 9d4:   094f2095    .word   0x094f2095
```

also my linker script:

```
ENTRY(start)
SECTIONS{

. = 0x10000;
.text : {*(.text)}
.data : {*(.data)}
.bss  : {*(.bss)}
. =ALIGN(8);
. =. + 0x1000;
stack_top = .;
. = . + 0x1000;
irq_stack_top = .;
}
```

Comment: @old_timer I added the disassembled code and the linker script. maybe I'm reading it wrong, but I think the linker script leaves space to copy the table into memory without overwriting anything.

Comment: okay so you are not loading this to run as the vector table, I get it, it can be done with qemu but you are loading as if it were a linux kernel?

Comment: maybe I can find some of my qemu bare metal code.

Answer (score 0):

So I do not have a complete example but something looks wrong, really wrong that you will need to sort out.  And maybe you are already through all of these basic steps to get to this point.

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel notmain.bin
```

Implies a binary memory image file as in objcopy -O binary is being used.  And there is no addressing information, so some default built into that machine or simulation is being used.  What is that address....

strap.s

```
    mov sp,#0x10000
    bl notmain
    b .

.globl GETPC
GETPC:
    mov r0,pc
    bx lr

.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr
```

notmain.c

```
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GETPC ( void );

#define UART_BASE 0x101F1000
#define UARTDR    (UART_BASE+0x000)

static void uart_send ( unsigned int x )
{
    PUT32(UARTDR,x);
}
static void hexstrings ( unsigned int d )
{
    unsigned int rb;
    unsigned int rc;

    rb=32;
    while(1)
    {
        rb-=4;
        rc=(d>>rb)&0xF;
        if(rc>9) rc+=0x37; else rc+=0x30;
        uart_send(rc);
        if(rb==0) break;
    }
    uart_send(0x20);
}
static void hexstring ( unsigned int d )
{
    hexstrings(d);
    uart_send(0x0D);
    uart_send(0x0A);
}
int notmain ( void )
{
    hexstring(GETPC());
    return(0);
}
```

uart address culled from the source code to qemu.  so far I find you can cheat and just write to the tx buffer, it does not actually emulate the time it takes to send out a character and overflow a fifo, etc.  So I cheat.

```
/* memmap */
MEMORY
{
    ram  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 32K
}

SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
   .bss  : { *(.text*) } > ram
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -march=armv4t strap.s -o strap.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -march=armv4t notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles strap.o notmain.o -T memmap -o notmain.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.elf -O binary notmain.bin
```

examine output

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <GETPC-0xc>:
   0:   e3a0d801    mov sp, #65536  ; 0x10000
   4:   eb000004    bl  1c <notmain>
   8:   eafffffe    b   8 <GETPC-0x4>

0000000c <GETPC>:
   c:   e1a0000f    mov r0, pc
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000014 <PUT32>:
  14:   e5801000    str r1, [r0]
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000001c <notmain>:
  1c:   e92d4070    push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
  20:   ebfffff9    bl  c <GETPC>
  24:   e3a04020    mov r4, #32
```

my entry point is where I want it. I am not loading an elf I am loading a binary image.  If I wanted the entry point to be different and load an elf it may be possible that using ENTRY() in the linker script then having the entry point wherever might work.

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel notmain.bin
```

then view the serial0 output of 00010014 so they are loading us at 0x10000 so change memmap

```
ram  : ORIGIN = 0x00010000, LENGTH = 32K
```

Now your linker script implies it should have put your code at 0x10000 but
clearly it has not based on your disassembly, so how are you running anything at all.  Also your entry point using a binary image is not the bootstrap it is not the first instructions you want to be executing.  maybe you disassembled an object not the final binary?

So for fun before changing the memory map to 0x10000 if I instead

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel notmain.elf
```

Then I get 00000014 on the output. it used the address defined in the elf file.

If I add this

```
    b .
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x10000
    bl notmain
    b .
```

and this

```
/* memmap */
ENTRY(_start)
MEMORY
{
    ram  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 32K
}

SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
   .bss  : { *(.text*) } > ram
}
```

and execute the elf I do get output of 00000018 so it is entering at the entry point not the first word of the loadable image.

run the .bin and you get no serial output as expected.

Change memmap to 0x10000 and run the elf you get 0x10018 as expected.

So that was a simple way to see how qemu loads our program.

so same build and linker script (with the 0x10000)

```
.globl _start
_start:
    ldr pc,reset_handler
    ldr pc,undefined_handler
    ldr pc,swi_handler
    ldr pc,prefetch_handler
    ldr pc,data_handler
    ldr pc,unused_handler
    ldr pc,irq_handler
    ldr pc,fiq_handler
reset_handler:      .word reset
undefined_handler:  .word hang
swi_handler:        .word swi
prefetch_handler:   .word hang
data_handler:       .word hang
unused_handler:     .word hang
irq_handler:        .word hang
fiq_handler:        .word hang

reset:
    mov r0,#0x10000
    mov r1,#0x00000
    ldmia r0!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}
    stmia r1!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}
    ldmia r0!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}
    stmia r1!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}

    ;@ FIQ 110 10001
    msr cpsr_c,#0xD1
    mov sp,#0x1000

    ;@ IRQ 110 10010
    msr cpsr_c,#0xD2
    mov sp,#0x2000

    ;@ SVC 110 10011
    msr cpsr_c,#0xD3
    mov sp,#0x3000

    ;@ ABT 110 10111
    msr cpsr_c,#0xD7
    mov sp,#0x4000

    ;@ UND 110 11011
    msr cpsr_c,#0xDB
    mov sp,#0x5000

    ;@ SYS 110 11111
    msr cpsr_c,#0xDF
    mov sp,#0x6000

    ;@ SVC 110 10011
    msr cpsr_c,#0xD3

    bl notmain
hang:
    b hang

swi:
    push {r4-r12,lr}
    bl swi_main
    pop {r4-r12,lr}
    movs pc,lr

.globl DO_SWI
DO_SWI:
    push {lr}
    svc 0
    pop {lr}
    bx lr

.globl GO_USER
GO_USER:
    ;@ USER 110 10000
    msr cpsr_c,#0xD0
    bl gouser
    b .
gouser:
    bx r0

.globl GETMODE
GETMODE:
    mrs r0,cpsr
    bx lr

.globl GETPC
GETPC:
    mov r0,pc
    bx lr

.globl GETSP
GETSP:
    mov r0,sp
    bx lr

.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr
```

and

```
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
unsigned int GETPC ( void );
unsigned int GETSP ( void );
unsigned int GETMODE ( void );
unsigned int GO_USER ( unsigned int );
unsigned int DO_SWI ( unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int );

#define UART_BASE 0x101F1000
#define UARTDR    (UART_BASE+0x000)
#define UARTFR    (UART_BASE+0x018)

static void uart_send ( unsigned int x )
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(GET32(UARTFR)&(1<<7)) break;
    }
    PUT32(UARTDR,x);
}
static void hexstrings ( unsigned int d )
{
    unsigned int rb;
    unsigned int rc;

    rb=32;
    while(1)
    {
        rb-=4;
        rc=(d>>rb)&0xF;
        if(rc>9) rc+=0x37; else rc+=0x30;
        uart_send(rc);
        if(rb==0) break;
    }
    uart_send(0x20);
}
static void hexstring ( unsigned int d )
{
    hexstrings(d);
    uart_send(0x0D);
    uart_send(0x0A);
}
unsigned int swi_main ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c, unsigned int d )
{
    hexstring(0xAABBCCDD);
    switch(a)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            return(~b);
        }
        case 1:
        {
            return(GETMODE());
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
void user_main ( void )
{
    hexstring(GETMODE());
    hexstring(GETSP());
    hexstring(DO_SWI(0,0x1234,0,0));
    hexstring(DO_SWI(1,0x1234,0,0));
}
int notmain ( void )
{
    hexstring(GETMODE());
    hexstring(GETSP());

    GO_USER((unsigned int)user_main);
    return(0);
}
```

get even a trivial swi in place first before attempting an interrupt.  getting the exception table in place, the banked stack registers, etc. seems trivial but even with experience those things bite you and you end up chasing the wrong thing.

```
400001D3 
00002FF8 
200001D0 
00005FF8 
AABBCCDD 
FFFFEDCB 
AABBCCDD 
600001D3
```

this was a bit overkill with mode changes and such, but it still has the swi handler in the right place.  The code is linked for

```
notmain.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00010000 <_start>:
   10000:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 10020 <reset_handler>
   10004:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 10024 <undefined_handler>
   10008:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 10028 <swi_handler>
   1000c:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 1002c <prefetch_handler>
   10010:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 10030 <data_handler>
   10014:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 10034 <unused_handler>
   10018:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 10038 <irq_handler>
   1001c:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 1003c <fiq_handler>

00010020 <reset_handler>:
   10020:   00010040    andeq   r0, r1, r0, asr #32

00010024 <undefined_handler>:
   10024:   00010090    muleq   r1, r0, r0
```

packing the exception table with its pc-relative addresses and letting the toolchain do all the work of sorting out addresses for you, you can then simply copy it to 0x00000000 from 0x10000.   It is probably fine but in your case I would at least put some level of alignment before your table, something makes me want to think it wants to be aligned.  However you wish to copy it is your deal, I would not use C in a bootstrap, the habit creates problems from time to time that are easily avoided.

Knowing what we know of course if we linked for address 0x00000000 and used the elf file then we do not have to copy/move the exception table.  It lands in the right place on load.

Newer cores have a VTOR register and you can simply choose a different exception or vector table address, but it does need to have a level of alignment that you cannot forget.

I did not go and research this timer, but I assume long before you attempted an interrupt you wrote very many throwaway programs that used polling to fully understand the timer and how to clear its interrupt, etc?  Depending on the chip (not necessarily core) then there may also be arm side registers you can poll, disable interrupts into the core, poll the gvic or vpic or whatever it is called and see the interrupt hit the edge of the core, be able to turn it off, etc.  Then.....enable it into the core now that you have mastered that peripheral.  Sometimes leaving nothing left to work on, for some cores though there is some interrupt stuff that can only be done in an isr (how to detect and clear the interrupt source) this virtual machine predates that by a long time though, so no worries there.

so...

If that is your linker script then why is your output zero based, and why is the uart function up front and not the bootstrap entry point?   If that is the disassembly of the final binary then there are all kinds of problems going on there.

I was seeing this as baremetal but forgetting qemu is loading linux-like so at some address like 0x8000, 0x10000, or 0x80000 are some examples, so yes you either need a core with a VTOR or copy the exception table over, and letting the tools build the addresses and pc-relative loads is the way to go.  That copy is probably fine if you are actually booting right and executing it.

Then have you completely mastered that peripheral?

This is an emulated core so it may resemble one/some of the products from arm but remember they are not all identical some come with interrupt controllers some do not, some folks like the raspi folks disable that interrupt controller, etc.  The base address of add on peripherals for real arm cores is based on the chip vendor not arm.  Etc....Best to dig through the source code for the specific machine emulation and see what it is doing to truly get a qemu machine to work.

So maybe you have done all of these things and it still does not work.  The question as written has some issues, the disassembly does not make sense for example.  Need to resolve that.   What if you try with an elf file first and an entry point then do the extra work to be able to run without the elf file and the bin file instead.  Do not re-write but add more content to the question if you need further help.  Unless someone else sees the issue with what has been presented.